# get value from listener -- method is undefindet for the type View.OnClickListener

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I tried this example from [Android: The method OnClickListener() is undefined for the type View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466744/android-the-method-onclicklistener-is-undefined-for-the-type-view) 
 but I get an error at .getC():

```
error at The method getC() is undefined for the type View.OnClickListener
```

hope someone can help me figure it out. or is there another possibility to get a value generated within a listener?

```
 View.OnClickListener myListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        double c;

        // in case you need to use C elsewhere
        public double getC() {
            return c;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // get A and B values
            // then use either
            c = a - b;
            // or I guess use 
            c = c - b;
        }
    };

    myButton.setOnClickListener(myListener);

    int x= myListener.getC();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare variables and -even public- methods inside an anonymous class, but there is no way you can reference them, since your class cannot be referenced.

You should change that anonymous class to nested in order to access the members and methods declared inside:

```
MyOnclickListener myListener = new MyOnclickListener();

private final class MyOnclickListener implements View.OnClickListener
{
    double c;

    // in case you need to use C elsewhere
    public double getC()
    {
        return c;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        // get A and B values
        // then use either
        c = a - b;
        // or I guess use
        c = c - b;
    }
}
```